# Can we say $ \left\| \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} x_n\right\|_{X} \geq C \|x_N\|_{X}$?

Tags: inequality, banach-spaces

Let$ (X, \|\cdot\|_{X})$ be a Banach space, and $\{x_n\}\subset X$.

> Can we say that $ \left\| \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} x_n\right\|_{X} \geq C \|x_N\|_{X}$ for some constant $C>0$ and some $N\in \mathbb N$?

Comment: What is $n$ on the right-hand side?

Comment: I meant. Some $n\in \mathbb N.$ (that some member of sequence $\{x_n\}_{n\in \mathbb N}$)

Comment: Obviously not. $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} x_n$ can be zero without any $x_n$ being zero.

Comment: Your question is horribly written. Can you please specify the quantifiers?

Answer (score 1):

Consider $(x_h)_h$ as $x_{2n}=\frac{(-1)^n}{n}$, and $x_{2n+1}=-x_{2n}$ . Then we end up with $0\geq C$, contradiction.

Thanks to the comments, I was totally wong.

Comment: Your series does not converge. What about trying $x_n = (-1)^n/n.$?

Comment: You obv right, post your answer since mine was wrong ;)

Comment: Just edit your answer.

Comment: @WillM.:  Note that $\sum \frac{(-1)^n}{n}$ is not zero.

Comment: That's true, that's $\log 2,$ i meant to say $x_{2n} = (-1)^n/n$ and $x_{2n+1} = -x_{2n}.$